# How do I read a fedora partition from windows?

Tags: windows, cross-platform, backup, disk-partitioning, ext3

Windows recognizes and gives my fedora partition a drive letter, but it shows it as blank. Is there a way to get windows to read ext3 filesystem?  Its a Fedora 10 partition.

Comment: Shouldn't this go to serverfault.com or superuser.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at [EXT2 IFS for Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html).

Several things to keep in mind with this.

- Ext3 is backwards compatible with Ext2, it just doesn't write to the journal
- NTFS is case insensitive, this may screw with you depending on what you are moving
- Some filenames that are valid in Ext2/3 are invalid in NTFS/VFAT like : and $
- Special files will be inaccessible, sockets, soft links, block devices
- permissions are not maintained
- Will not work with LVM volumes

It will let you read and write to it though ;)

Comment: this is what i just downloaded, i'll tell you all how it works when i install it.

Comment: unfortunately it's an LVM partition!!!

Comment: :( LVM, not sure if there is an LVM handler for windows.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to my similar question on ServerFault.com:

- [What Windows ext3 driver should I use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3038/what-windows-ext3-driver-should-i-use)

Summary of the best answer I got (and other answers were later deleted, I assume by their authors):  Use ntfs-3g to access the NTFS filesystem from Linux.  You will have a much smaller chance of filesystem corruption doing it this way than using any of the existing ext2/3 drivers from Windows.

Comment: way to link to a private beta

Comment: I think he just wants to gloat about having an invite. ;)

Comment: Check out the blog.  At the bottom of every StackOverflow page is a link to the blog.  There are two recent blog entries directly related to the beta of ServerFault.

Comment: @ryansstack:  If a question is closed as "belongs on serverfault" then it appears to automatically be moved over there.  I figured, therefore, that it was acceptable to crosslink.

Comment: To whomever downvoted my answer:  What about my answer is incorrect or offensive?

Answer (score 0):

I know that you want to mount your Fedora partition but from experience I have found that the best way to share a partition with Windows is to format as NTFS and use ntfs-3g to access it in Linux.

I tried using the ext2 Windows app mentioned by JensenDied a couple of years ago and ended up having problems accessing data on the USB drive that it was being used with.